# Can not find the native method in js

Tags: react-native

I created CalendarManager class in ios native module:

```
@implementation CalendarManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(@"CalendarManager");

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location) {
  RCTLogInfo(@"Pretending to create an event %@ at %@", name, location);
}

@end
```

and use it in js module :

```
componentWillMount() {
    let CalendarManager = NativeModules.CalendarManager;
    console.log(CalendarManager);
    CalendarManager.addEvent('Birthday Party', '4 private drive, surrey');
  }
```

then I encountered error: `Can not read property 'add Event' of undefined`. obviously this error told me that `CalendarManager` hasn't been imported.
Anything I did wrong ?

Comment: Where is the CalendarManager defined? in the iOS project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter question. it works when I remove RCT_EXPORT_MODULE's parameter, or change parameter @"CalendarManager" to CalendarManager.